# Microsoft Office on a low-spec netbook

Tags: windows-7, performance, microsoft-office

I just installed MS office 2007 on a very old netbook. I only needed Word and Excel but I mistakenly installed the whole suite. How much of an impact will this have on the overall speed of the system?

Answer (score 1):

Open `Controlpanel->Programs & Features`, select `Office 2007` and click change Features and uninstall the other not used features to free some HDD space.

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly waste hard drive space, but speed shouldn't be a concern.

Uninstall the components you don't need and you're golden.